# how to sync data in collection with List<GameObject> in Unity?

Tags: c#, arrays, unity-game-engine, collections

Supposedly I have a collection of data from network, the network send these data every frame:

```
public class Unit {
    public float PosX;
    public float PosY;
    public float Health;
}

public Unit[] DataFromNetwork;
```

And I want to convert to this:

```
public class MonoUnit : MonoBehaviour {
    public Transform t;  // from Transform
    public float health
}
```

How to transform DataFromNetwork to Gameobjects every frame?

I could think of this way:
- Destroy all GameObject and instantiate it based on DataFromNetwork every frame.
but I think that would be a bad idea because of GameObject should be long living.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's better to add a unique `id` to your `Unit` in `DataFromNetwork` and in the first call of `Instatiate` for each unit, assign this `id` to your unit.
In the next received package, find your unit in the game by `id` and assign your new data to it.

Comment: hello thank you for answer, what if the DataFromNetwork on the next frame comes with more/less Unit than previous frame

Comment: It's OK! because you read DataFromNetwork  one by one, and search for ids that exists in this list.

Comment: By the way, if you meant that you want to remove a Unit if it doesn't exist on DataFromNetwork array, or you want to Instantiate if it's a new unit, you can do it by a Boolean flag on DataFromNetwork and MonoUnit.

Comment: Yes, some unit can be already removed from DataFromNetwork which make some MonoUnit out of sync, thus needs to be destroyed. Also there can be more unit from DataFromNetwork, this one can be solved with your answer (instantiate and assign id to update). The boolean flag should be on monounit or DataFromNetwork?

Comment: change flag of every unit that you update (in monounit) , and when finished, destroy whatever that has a false flag.